# Friend Function needs a Helper Function

Tags: c++, friend

In my `.h` file, I have a class like this:

```cpp
#pragma once
class Widget {
    int private_data;
    friend void foo(Widget& w);
}
```

As I was implementing `foo`, it turns out I need a helper function:

```cpp
static void foohelper(Widget& w) {
    printf("further processing %d", w.private_data);
}

void foo(Widget& w) {
    printf("processing %d", w.private_data);
    foohelper(w);
}
```

I don't want to put `foohelper` in the `.h` file, because it is an implementation detail, but that means there's no way for it to become a `friend` directly.

In this example, one could get away with just passing the `private_data` directly, but in a real use case, this doesn't scale well when `Widget` has more private variables.

I only ever call `foohelper` from `foo`, so if c++ supported nested function definitions, I wouldn't have a problem:

```cpp
void foo(Widget& w) {
    void foohelper(Widget& w) { // compiler: function definition is not allowed here
         printf("further processing %d", w.private_data);
    }
    printf("processing %d", w.private_data);
    foohelper(w);
}
```

But, c++ doesn't allow this as a solution.

Is it possible for a function to pass `friend` status to a helper function?

Comment: "I don't want to put foohelper in the .h file, because it is an implementation detail" But if you put it in the class definition in the header, it will be private (which is the default privacy level of a class)

Comment: @EdwardKarak: `foohelper` is an implementation detail of `foo`, not of `Widget`...

Comment: @Jarod42 `foohelper` is an implementation detail of `Widget`. Why else would it need a `Widget` argument, whose private members it accesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't have inner function, but you can use lambda for that:

```
void foo(Widget& w) {
    auto foohelper = [](Widget& w) {
         printf("further processing %d", w.private_data);
    };
    printf("processing %d", w.private_data);
    foohelper(w);
}
```